# FFMPEG Stream to Instagram Via instafeed.me OR YellowDuck

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, instagram, rtmp, rtmps

I'm trying to do video stream via RTMP to Instagram with FFMPEG

I'm able to do it to facebook and twitter, but instagram is an other beast...

when I create a live broadcast in [rtmp.in](https://rtmp.in) or yellowduck I get a stream key

when I do this

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 256M -re -i file.webm -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 720x1280 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/--key--here--
```

ffmpeg outputs nothing, no error and I see no video in instafeed panel :(

In other network I got sometimes error in ffmpeg log... but when it's to instagram : just blank nothing

what do I miss?

here the log

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

and completely blank, no error, no framerate infos like any other transcoding...

Comment: Show the **complete** log from ffmpeg (without the stream key).

Comment: @llogan See the edit, I added the log but usually in other networks, I see the fps and some extra infos or if any error I see the error, but when it's to instafeed.me or yellowduck; just blank, no info, no log, no error.... just blank

Comment: If you output to a local file (`output.flv` instead of `rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/--key--here--`) does it work? If yes, then it is a network related issue.

Comment: @llogan yes, when I change to file.mp4 it's working. but in other site, when there is an error i see some error message with stuff like wrong format... but live-upload.instagram.com says nothing, just blank

Comment: Wrap the output in quotes: `"rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/--key--here--"`

Comment: @llogan working ;) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the output in quotes:

```
"rtmps://live-upload.instagram.com:443/rtmp/--key--here--"
```